# Purchase Order physical receipt on AX2012 Enterprise Portal

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal, purchase-order

What are the steps to create a receipt of PO on portal? I don't see any button, but just **unconfirmed product receipt.**

Do we have this possibility at all? Cause as I know we can't perform any "Edit" or modifications on Purchase Orders on Enterprise Portal.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this programming related?

Comment: More functional question